# Validar checkbox si se ha checkado un elemento que desparasca el mensaje requerido

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Estimados apoyo con la validacion de una matriz de checkbox, solo la validacion del checkbox no me funciona el onblur, al seleccionar un chekbox y pasar al estado true deberia desaparecer el mensaje lo intentado pero no logro remover el mensaje requerido es sobre los ckeckbox de la parte de rubros dejo el codigo y una imagen para que sea mas claro la explicacion.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { preRegisterAddNew } from "../../redux/actions/PreRegister";
import { useForm } from "../../hooks/useForm";

export const FormPreRegistro = ({ handleValidated }) => {

  const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});

  const validateForm = () => {
    let errors = {};
  
    if (!idFiscal.trim()) {
      errors.idFiscal = "El campo 'idFiscal' es requerido";
    }
  
    if (!pais.trim()) {
      errors.pais = "El campo 'Pais' es requerido";
    }

    if (!rubrosFilter) {
      errors.rubrosFilter = "El campo 'Rubro' es requerido";
      console.log("rubrosFilter", rubrosFilter);
    }

    if (!empresa.trim()) {
      errors.empresa = "El campo 'Empresa' es requerido";
    }
  
    if (!comprador.trim()) {
      errors.comprador = "El campo 'Comprador' es requerido";
    } 
  
    if (!comentario.trim()) {
      errors.comentario = "El campo 'Contacto y/o Comentario' es requerido";
    } 
  
    return errors;
  
   }

  let paises = [
    { value: "", label: "[Seleccione Pais]" },
    { value: "1", label: "Perú" },
    { value: "2", label: "Chile" },
    { value: "3", label: "Argentina" },
    { value: "4", label: "Brasil" },
    { value: "5", label: "México" },
  ];

  let empresas = [
    { value: "", label: "[Seleccione Empresa]" },
    { value: "1", label: "Empresa 1" },
    { value: "2", label: "Empresa 2" },
    { value: "3", label: "Empresa 3" },
    { value: "4", label: "Empresa 4" },
    { value: "5", label: "Empresa 5" },
  ];

  let compradores = [
    { value: "", label: "[Seleccione Comprador]" },
    { value: "1", label: "Comprador 1" },
    { value: "2", label: "Comprador 2" },
    { value: "3", label: "Comprador 3" },
    { value: "4", label: "Comprador 4" },
    { value: "5", label: "Comprador 5" },
  ];

  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(false);
  const [isChecked, setisChecked] = useState([]);

  

  useEffect(() => {
    let isChecked = [
      { id: 1, value: "Rubro 1" },
      { id: 2, value: "Rubro 2" },
      { id: 3, value: "Rubro 3" },
      { id: 4, value: "Rubro 4" },
    ];

    setisChecked(
      isChecked.map((d) => {
        return {
          select: false,
          id: d.id,
          value: d.value,
        };
      })
    );

  }, []);

  const handleBlur = (e) => {
    handleInputChange(e);
    setErrors(validateForm(formValues));
};

  const [formValues, handleInputChange] = useForm({
    idFiscal: "",
    pais: "",
    empresa: "",
    comprador: "",
    comentario: "",
    rubrosFilter: ""
    
  });

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const { idFiscal, pais, rubrosFilter, empresa, comprador, comentario } = formValues;

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    const rubrosFilter = isChecked.filter((item) => item.select === true);
    console.log("rubrosFilter", rubrosFilter);
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(
      preRegisterAddNew(
        idFiscal,
        pais,
        rubrosFilter,
        empresa,
        comprador,
        comentario
      )
    );
    handleValidated();
  };

  return (
    <form name="form" className="form-group" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div className="row">
        <div className="form-group col-12 mb-3">
          <label htmlFor="idFiscal">N° Id. Fiscal</label>
          <input
            className="form-control"
            type="text"
            name="idFiscal"
            autoComplete="off"
            value={idFiscal}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
            onBlur={handleBlur}
          />
          {errors.idFiscal && <span className="text-danger">{errors.idFiscal}</span>}
        </div>
        <div className="form-group col-12 mb-3">
          <label htmlFor="pais">País</label>
          <select
            className="form-select"
            name="pais"
            value={pais}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
            onBlur={handleBlur}
          >
            {paises.map((item) => {
              return (
                <option name="pais" key={item.value} value={item.label}>
                  {item.label}
                </option>
              );
            })}
          </select>
          {errors.pais && <span className="text-danger">{errors.pais}</span>}
        </div>
        <div className="form-group col-md-12 col-12 mb-3">
          <label htmlFor="rubro">Seleccione Rubro</label>
          <div className="multiselect">
            <div className="selectBox"></div>
            <div className="checkboxes overflow-auto">
              {isChecked.map((d) => (
                <div key={d.id}>
                  <span>
                    <input
                      onChange={(event) => {
                        let checked = event.target.checked;
                        setisChecked(
                          isChecked.map((data) => {
                            if (d.id === data.id) {
                              data.select = checked;
                            } 
                            return data;
                          })
                        );
                      }}
                      type="checkbox"
                      name="rubrosFilter"
                      checked={d.select}
                      value={rubrosFilter}
                      onBlur={handleBlur}
                                         
                      
                    ></input>
                  </span>
                  <span>{d.value}</span>
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
            {errors.rubrosFilter && <span className="text-danger">{errors.rubrosFilter}</span>}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="form-group col-12 mb-3">
          <label htmlFor="empresa">Empresa a postular</label>
          <select
            className="form-select"
            name="empresa"
            value={empresa}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
            onBlur={handleBlur}
          >
            {empresas.map((item) => {
              return (
                <option name="empresa" key={item.value} value={item.label}>
                  {item.label}
                </option>
              );
            })}
          </select>
          {errors.empresa && <span className="text-danger">{errors.empresa}</span>}
        </div>
        <div className="form-group col-12 mb-3">
          <label htmlFor="comprador">Comprador responsable</label>
          <select
            className="form-select"
            name="comprador"
            value={comprador}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
            onBlur={handleBlur}
          >
            {compradores.map((item) => {
              return (
                <option name="comprador" key={item.value} value={item.label}>
                  {item.label}
                </option>
              );
            })}
          </select>
          {errors.comprador && <span className="text-danger">{errors.comprador}</span>}
        </div>
        <div className="form-group col-12 mb-3">
          <label htmlFor="comentario">Contacto y/o Comentario</label>
          <textarea
            className="form-control"
            name="comentario"
            disabled={disabled}
            value={comentario}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
            onBlur={handleBlur}
          ></textarea>
          {errors.comentario && <span className="text-danger">{errors.comentario}</span>}
        </div>
        <div className="d-grid gap-2">
          <button type="submit" className="btn bg-button block subtitle">
            Validar
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: select: false esto esta mal; puede ser true o falso no ???

Comment: concejo de vida separa tu codigo javascript de tu HTML XD

Comment: ok tomare tu consejo esto esta en desarollo todavia, podrias poner la correcion como deberia ser. gracias.

Comment: estoy buscando en el código en onde haces la validación del si esta checado el checkbox... como tienes todo mesclado es un problema leer tu código y entenderlo ...

Comment: Gracias. lo tendre en cuenta

Comment: oye esto es lo que dices que te molesta? `if (!rubrosFilter) {      errors.rubrosFilter = "El campo 'Rubro' es requerido";    }`

Comment: si al dar a un check el mensaje deberia borrarse. ya que pasa al estado true

Comment: Solo pasas uno ; esa condicional esta mal creo; se supone que si alguno de los 4 rubros es true entonces no debe salir ese mensaje cierto??

Comment: donde esta el codigo de `rubrosFilter` son ideas mias o no lo agregaste?

Comment: en le handleSubmit, const rubrosFilter = isChecked.filter((item) => item.select === true);

Comment: eso te evalua uno a uno pero te retornara solo el ultimo si mas no me equivoco...

Comment: no entiendo bien tu pregunta, la validacion lo que hace es al dar click en las casillas el focus se activan los mensajes, al llenarlos se borran, solo el del check rubro no desaprace el mensaje al dar check a un valor.

Comment: es por la forma en que estas validandolo; tiene que verificar que resultado tiene esa validacion con console.log

Comment: por que no agregas la salida de esto: `console.log("rubrosFilter", rubrosFilter);`

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130598/discussion-between-sixto-mujica-and-arcanis-the-omnipotent).

Answer (score 0):

Hay dos lugares donde se debe usar lógica para saber el estado `isChecked`, reactJS lo controla con los `checkboxes` del formulario, el uso es:

1. Al validar el form.
2. Al enviar los datos al Backend.

Sugiero usar programación funcional en el componente, codificando una función local que ayudará a filtrar solo `checkboxes` activados:

```
function filterChecked(){
  return isChecked.filter((item) => item.select === true);
}
```

Después, se llama a la función donde es necesario, por ejemplo en `handleSubmit`:

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    const rubrosFilter = filterChecked();
    console.log("rubrosFilter", rubrosFilter);
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(
      preRegisterAddNew(
        idFiscal,
        pais,
        rubrosFilter,
        empresa,
        comprador,
        comentario
      )
    );
    handleValidated();
  };
```

Y en `validateForm`:

```
const validateForm = () => {
    let errors = {};
  
    //codigo

    if (filterChecked().length === 0) {
     errors.isChecked = "El campo 'Rubro' es requerido";
      console.log("isChecked", isChecked);
    }

    //codigo
  
    return errors;
  
}
```

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.